# How can i retrieve the currencies in Django moneyed and diaplay them on a react frontend?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have been trying to get the list of currencies from django moneyed by importing either the CURRENCIES or list_all_currencies function and sending that list to the frontend to populate a dropdown but I always get Serializer errors

E.g.
TypeError(f'Object of type {o.**class**.**name**} '

TypeError:Object of type Currency is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to retrieve the currencies.

From djmoney.settings import CURRENCY_CHOICES

And send these CURRENCY_CHOICES to the fronted

the code looks like this

```
from djmoney.settings import CURRENCY_CHOICES

 class CurrencyList(APIView):

       def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
           return Response(CURRENCY_CHOICES,status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

populate a dropdown on the frontend with the list from this response

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Not sure why it would be necessary to pass this data in an API, unless you are often changing the CURRENCY_CHOICES. Better to make a separate constant in your frontend.